# Share directory inside docker container to host local directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a directory inside my docker container `/var/www/example` (includes site files) Files are populated when the docker image is built and up. I will update the code sometimes and will replace changed files with rsync and I want to share `/var/www/example` dir to host machine ./www dir. I created docker-compose.yml (nginx,php-fpm,mariadb)

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    volumes:
  - "./www:/var/www/example"
```

and if turn on the volumes option, it replaces my `/var/www/example` to empty by `./www` dir but I need reverse, files from container must be showing in local host dir `./www` how I can do that?

Comment: With the set of tasks you describe, I wouldn't use a Docker volume at all.  When you update the code, commit it to source control, `docker-compose build` a new image, and use `docker-compose up` to automatically stop, delete, and recreate the container.  The approach you describe is prone to losing data if the container does get deleted, and if the system fails in some way you can't easily tell exactly what code it was running at the point it failed.

Answer (score 0):

That is how the docker volume work, it need to respect the host volume, and apply any change on host volume to the container. I think you just need to populate your source code into your host volume first. Otherwise, if you need to keep the current logic, you can simply populate your source code in the container to another folder, let's say `/var/www/example2` and on your entrypoint or run command, you run `cp -r /var/www/example2 /var/www/example`.

P/s: I think you will need to check if the `/var/www/example` folder is empty before doing the copy.

There is an docker image named Mautic also is doing the same as your. They download the source code from the internet when the container start and populate to the volume.